# Why is if (data) not working in this code?

Tags: reactjs, if-statement

Ok, so for some reason, the if (error) and if (data) actions don't work in this code, and I can't figure out why. Nothing is console logging, and if(data) doesn't reset the form error to null. Can anyone help?

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { supabase } from "../config/supabaseClient";

const Create = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const [formError, setFormError] = useState(null);

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!text) {
      setFormError("Please add your verse text");
      return;
    }

    const { data, error } = await supabase
      .from("notes_strings")
      .insert([{ text }]);

    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      setFormError("Please add your verse text");
    }
    if (data) {
      console.log(data);
      setFormError(null);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="note create">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label htmlFor="text">Enter Verse:</label>
        <textarea
          id="note"
          value={text}
          onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
        />

        <button>Add Verse</button>

        {formError && <p className="error">{formError}</p>}
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Create;
'''
```

The input verse gets added to the database, so that part is working, as is the if (error). I was expecting the data to log and the error message to reset to null when a new verse was input, but those things do not happen. Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: When you debug, what do `error` and `data` contain?  What does the call to `supabase` return when you don't destructure the result?

Comment: The error is typically a repeat text, so I get the error message that the unique constraint is violated unless the textarea is empty, in which case, nothing is logged. Data shows nothing, but the entry still shows up in the database.

Comment: What *specific* and *exact* value (with any sensitive string values replaced of course) is returned from that `supabase` operation?  Log it to the console just before the `if (error)` operation.  What gets logged?

Comment: Ok, the error message is `{code: '23505', details: null, hint: null, message: 'duplicate key value violates unique constraint "notes_strings_text_key"'}code: "23505"details: nullhint: nullmessage: "duplicate key value violates unique constraint \"notes_strings_text_key\""[[Prototype]]: Object` and the data is null!

Comment: That looks like something else to investigate then.  For the question being asked above, the answer as to why `data` and `error` are empty is simply because that object has no such properties.  It sounds like you have some additional debugging to do in order to narrow down the problem, as it's not what/where you assumed it was.

Comment: Hmm... ok. I wonder why the data would come back null if the entry is being inserted into the db table. It does appear that everything else is working as it should.